# If wet skin has a higher coefficient of friction that dry skin, why is it easier to remove a ring from a wet finger than a dry one?

Tags: friction

Simply from personal experience it's clear that removing a ring from a finger that is wet is easier than dry (I can pull a ring over the knuckle without even twisting it while wet but have to twist while skin is dry).

However, from this article https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/159150092.pdf, it's shown wet skin has a higher coefficient of friction with materials rings are commonly made of. Is there a factor besides the friction coefficient that's relevant here?

Comment: I have more trouble removing my ring when my finger is wet. Much more trouble.

Comment: I guess I should clarify it's when it's completely saturated, as in dripping wet.

Comment: was there maybe soap left over in your "dripping wet" ?

Comment: No there definitely was not soap, but it was American tap water so maybe there's something in there... I didn't think of that.

Comment: Oh, you know what. There is a difference between hard and soft water. When I wash my hands with soft water it always feels like there is still soap on them even though there isn't whereas with hardwater my hands feel squeaks against itself.

Comment: Ah that's probably it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me distinguish between damp skin and wet skin.

Make your hands wet and allow the water to soak into your skin. You can speed up the process of water soaking into your skin with a bit of warmth. Rub you wet hands together, vigorously.

As long as there is still plenty of water the layer of water *on* your skin is acting as a lubricant.

(Water is actually a good lubricant, it's just that for obvious reasons we don't use it as lubricant for metal parts.)

As you are rubbing: you arrive at a point where there is no more water *on* your skin, but your skin is damp now. If you need grip, this is the moment to seize. If you need grip to screw the lid off an unopened jar, this is the moment.

Continue rubbing and the water evaporates out of your skin, and the amount of grip you have goes down again.